# Why are GIF animations so intensive to load on websites compared to Mp4?

Tags: animation, gif, file-size, animated-gif

The exact same animation rendered as a 30 mb mp4 video, as well as a 30 mb gif animation, we would see the web server struggle to load the Gif animation for autoplay even though both files are the exact same size for the identical animation. Why is this? What makes web streaming so difficult for loading Gifs versus loading mp4s?

Comment: It's because when you view an MP4 over the web, you don't have to download each full frame to see it play back. You only need to be sent the data (the pixels) that change from frame to frame. Also the image itself is compressed similar to a JPEG (lossy compression), whereas GIFs use a kind of lossless compression which is much less efficient for photographic images. If you are interested in delving into video formats in more depth, probably better to ask on Video Production Stack Exchange. Video is generally off-topic here.

Comment: hope this animation question could remain here. if your comment is converted to answer i can mark it as best